# 302 redirects being cached in firefox

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www.google.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^dir/file.html http://domain.tld/dir/index.html [L,R=302]
```

When I visit my site by clicking on it in the Google SERP it showsme dir/file.html. If I hit F5 to refresh it does the redirect. But then if I try to go to http://domain.tld/dir/file.html from dir/index.html I can't. I get 302 redirected, once again, to the index.

It's as though the browser is caching the 302 redirect when the only redirects it should be capturing are 301 redirects.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don’t you want to let me, the user that googled for your content, reach that content directly? I would report such a case to Google via their abuse form, because you are trying to cheat.

Comment: 302 responses are generally cacheable, depending on what the exact response headers are.  What _are_ the exact response headers in your case?